# MySQL ExecuteNonQuery() does nothing

Tags: mysql

I have the most simple code...

```
// Connect to database etc
string sqlStr = "INSERT INTO .... ... ";
MySqlCom.CommandText = sqlStr;
int n = MySqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have looked over this code 100 times, and just cant figure it out, its like im looking in the wrong database but im not... im sure of it.

The n even returns with say 1, but the data just isnt in the database after the code executes. It doesn't fail, it doesn't complain about anything, and i can copy the sqlStr into the Workbench and it works perfectly.

Is there any circumstance that MySQL would execute the code but not actually write the data to the database, and not throw an error?

Comment: Please retag your question with the computer language it's about, so it has a chance of being reviewed by the appropriate people.

Comment: There is no magic behind it, the most obvious answers are often the good ones. Are you 100% sure you looked in the GOOD DATABASE and in the GOOD ENVIRONMENT (it's a common error to insert stuff in test database and look for it in acceptance environment...) ?

Comment: I know! its crazy right... im 1000000% sure its the correct database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any circumstance that MySQL would execute the code but not
>   actually write the data to the database, and not throw an error?

When you use transactions and don't issue a commit.

Comment: You are absolutely correct... and as it turned out the problem WAS to do with my connection code, it was randomly connecting to the wrong database - this made it quite difficult to figure out... why you ask, well i was using a connection objected that "could" be connected to either database 1 or 2, and didnt close the connection so that if another request came along it could just use the open connection... speeds things up fanatically... but I forgot to check if the existing connection object was in fact connected to the correct database... fail!! :(